# PostgreSQL 9.5 - Start Server not error but postmaster.pid not created

Tags: database, postgresql

I get some stuck after 3 hours find the issue. I get issue (but before i restart the Ubuntu, the Postgre working fine) :

> Start Server not error but postmaster.pid not created

I use this syntax to start Postgre process:

```
/usr/local/pgsql95/bin/pg_ctl -D /home/kitty/mydatabasedatafolder/ -l myfilelog start
```

Anyone can help the issues ?

Comment: Did you run this with `postgres` user ? What is the output of `pg_lsclusters`

Comment: yes i use postgres user

Comment: I cannot find pg_lsclusters file, where it should exist ?

Comment: Maybe it is not installed. Make user user postgres can read and write to `/home/kitty/mydatabasedatafolder/`

Comment: Can it missing ? before Postgre working normally before i restart the Ubuntu

Comment: If the file was not created, PostgreSQL did not start. Look at the `myfilelog` that you providently created.